# Rust Tokio Async performance

Tags: performance, rust, rust-tokio, low-latency

I'm looking to create a high throughput, low-latency marketplace using Rust. I was doing some performance testing on the serialization and found that it was pretty slow (0.05ms). After some investigation I found that using Tokio and Async with Rust slowed down code that is just part of a function that has an await in it.

I have two main questions:

1. Is there any information on why this might be?
2. How can I trace the code to see exactly what's being run so I can find out what's going on (I've done profiling already using perf and hotspot).

Below is the code that I've created that shows the performance difference. It runs a "with_await" and a "without_await" function in two configurations, once just by awaiting and once as a spawned future, and both show similar performance.
(These times are in ms)

```
with_await 0.04643426799999998
without_await 0.009190136999999998
without_await 0.009858687000000007
with_await 0.050352950999999944
```

```rust
use std::time::{Duration, SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};
use serde_json::Value;
use tokio::time::sleep;

static JSON_BLOB: &str = "{\"arg\":{\"channel\":\"basket_orders\",\"order_name\":\"socks\"},\"data\":[{\"prices\":[[\"15.15\",\"22.22\",\"12.5\",\"22.0\"]],\"amounts\":[[\"10\",\"20\",\"10\",\"15\"]],\"ts\":\"1680917016349\"}]}";

pub fn utcnow() -> Duration {
    SystemTime::now().duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap()
}

async fn with_await() {
    let mut diff_sum = 0_f64;
    for count in 1..=1000 {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1)).await;
        let blah: &str = JSON_BLOB.as_ref();
        let received_time = utcnow().as_nanos();
        let value: Value = serde_json::from_str(blah).unwrap();
        let millis_diff = (utcnow().as_nanos() - received_time) as f64 / 1_000_000.0;
        diff_sum += millis_diff;
    }
    println!("with_await {}", diff_sum / 1000_f64);
}

async fn without_await() {
    let mut diff_sum = 0_f64;
    for count in 1..=1000 {
        let blah: &str = JSON_BLOB.as_ref();
        let received_time = utcnow().as_nanos();
        let value: Value = serde_json::from_str(blah).unwrap();
        let millis_diff = (utcnow().as_nanos() - received_time) as f64 / 1_000_000.0;
        diff_sum += millis_diff;
    }
    println!("without_await {}", diff_sum / 1000_f64);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    with_await().await;
    without_await().await;

    let mut handles = vec![];
    handles.push(tokio::spawn(with_await()));
    handles.push(tokio::spawn(without_await()));
    futures::future::join_all(handles).await;
}
```

Dependencies are:

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.3.28"
serde = "1.0.159"
serde_json = "1.0.95"
tokio = { version = "1.27.0", features = ["full"] }
```

Comment: I haven't fully examined your code but instead _with or without_ `await` you might want to evaluate it like _with or without_ `tokio::time::sleep`. For some reason tokio `sleep` requires an additional **1ms**, not sure it is because of tokio executor or related with internal implementation of sleep. Please see the [code & results here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=9aa2c0bde7e279df4215ea00be611f41) .If `sleep` is not going to be used in my  code like that I wouldn't use it for benchmarking.

Comment: For me there is no significant difference, did you test without `--release`?

Comment: @ÖmerErden So the `sleep.await` is added in to replicate an `await` on another function in the actual code, specifically reading off a tcp websocket connection. I see exactly the same behaviour if I do that.
Also, it's important here that the timing is done after the await has been called, so the timing doesn't include the await.

Comment: @cafce25 What is "significant" for you? Here, even when using the rust playground I'm seeing a difference in speed of 2, which for my purposes is significant.

Comment: It could be related to a loss of precision when casting the result of `as_nanos()`, that is a `u128` to `f64`. As of 2023, the nano values are on the order of 1e19, but an f64 can only store around 15 digits, that means that you may lose a few hundred nanoseconds each loop. Do that 1000 times and you lose a few hundred microseconds, that is a fraction of a millisecond, that is what you are seeing. And maybe the `sleep().await` syncs the clock with a nanosecond with always the same ending digits, making the rounding different.

Comment: Or it could just be that the "sleep().await" have quite some code behind, and although you are not timing it, it is poisoning the locality of your CPU cache.

Comment: I'll check the u128 stuff, with 1000 runs only I don't think that's enough runs to have a significant impact on the timing.

I'll also check maybe something with the cache misses, but cache misses are on the magnitude of 1-5 nanoseconds, so that shouldn't have a huge impact on the performance here.

If I find an answer I'll report back, thanks all :)